# Set default value to variable declared later on?

Tags: python, default-arguments

I'm a student that's very VERY new to python and trying to self-teach. I have experience with Java, but thinking from a compiled language to an interpreted language is proving to be quite difficult. In a personal project I'm currently working on, I want to set the default value for my variable `location` in my `Thing` class to `rooms[6]`, which I declare later on. The problem is, the `Room` object which I create is inherited from my `Thing` class, therefore I can't create the array of `Room`s (`rooms[]`) before the initialization of my `Thing` class.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, name=None, location=rooms[6]):  # rooms is not defined
        if name == None:
            pass
        else:
            self.name = name
            self.location = location

class Room(Thing):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.connectsTo = []

    def connectRoom(self, r):
        if not r in self.connectsTo:
            self.connectsTo.append(r)

rooms = []
roomNames = {"Kitchen", "Living Room", "Garden", "Game Room",
             "Library", "Office", "Great Hall", "Den", "Dining Room"}
for name in roomNames:
    rooms.append(Room(name))
```

is there any way to work around this, or should I just restructure my entire code? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Typically, you'd just have it default to `None`, then do a `if location is None:` check internally.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Python (or at least CPython) is just as compiled as Java; both compile to byte code execute by a virtual machine. They differ in typing (Java is statically typed, Python is dynamically typed), and functions and classes are first-class objects in Python, but not Java. As a result, there is a lot of stuff you can do at run-time in Python that you cannot do in Java.